# A website page within a website page

Tags: html, wordpress, web

Ok, I have a website page within a site and the website works perfect. when the page within a page loads, i get scroll down bar with the page within a page. how can I make the page within a page load without having the scroll bar and just self adjust itself to fit the page? confusing I know but here is a simple code that im using .

[dciframe]http://yahoo.com/,100%,1500px,0,auto,border:1px solid blue;align:left;[/dciframe]

Comment: A page within a page is called a frame.

Comment: I think that he refers to IFrame Widget (Wordpress)

Answer (score 1):

Change the 5th parameter from `auto` to `no`:

```
[dciframe]http://yahoo.com/,100%,1500px,0,auto,border:1px solid blue;align:left;[/dciframe]
```

to:

```
[dciframe]http://yahoo.com/,100%,1500px,0,no,border:1px solid blue;align:left;[/dciframe]
```

see explanation in the first paragraph [*here*](http://wordpress.org/plugins/iframe-widget/faq/)